# NVD3 tooltip hides below other divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, nvd3.js

I am trying to get the NVD3 tooltip to go above all other divs. The problem is that I have three charts in a row, and very large tooltips that spill out of their div. I can set the z-index on one or the other side, but one will always be below another.

For example, if I set the center div to have the highest z-index, then the tooltip generated from the left or right side is cut off in the center area, and so on.

Changing the z-index of the tooltip doesn't have any effect, as it's ultimately a child of the respective chart. How can I make it stay above everything?

Comment: You don't want them to overlap at all or you just want one to be above all the others?

Comment: I want the tooltip that appears when you mouse over the nvd3 chart to be above everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix was to add a CSS3 hover selector to the divs that increased the z-index.